# Replace python tkinter label widget with entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to enable double click to edit a label. Is there a way to replace the label, which user double-clicks, with entry widget without destroying it?
This example lists label widgets and after double-click destroys it and sets entry widget at the end:

```
from tkinter import *
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.tasks = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
        self.list_tasks()
    def list_tasks(self):
        self.tasks_frame = Frame(self.root)
        for task in self.tasks:
            task_label = Label(self.tasks_frame, text=task)
            task_label.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.replace_with_entry)
            task_label.pack()
        self.tasks_frame.pack()
    def replace_with_entry(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.destroy()
        entry_widget = Entry(self.tasks_frame)
        entry_widget.pack()
root = Tk()
main_window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want entry widget in exactly the same place, where label was. I think it is possible with grid, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is not to replace it, but to instead *overlay* it. This is one circumstance where `place` is very useful.

For example:

```
def replace_with_entry(self, event):
    widget = event.widget
    entry_widget = Entry(widget)
    entry_widget.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
    entry_widget.bind("<Return>", self.remove_entry)
    entry_widget.focus_set()

def remove_entry(self, event):
    entry = event.widget
    label = entry.place_info()["in"]
    label.configure(text=entry.get())
    entry.destroy()
```

Comment: Beet me to it. Though your solution takes less code.

Comment: I like the use of place here. I was going to replace the label widget at the grid location with an entry widget and then replace entry with a label widget with the `get()` value. However the way you do it is much cleaner.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The nice thing about place is that the solution is completely independent on whether you use `pack` or `grid` or anything else. These sorts of problems are where `place` really shines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the grid solution. I think it is acceptable, but you can wait to see if someone else provides a better solution.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.tasks = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
        self.list_tasks()
    def list_tasks(self):
        self.tasks_frame = Frame(self.root)
        for i, task in enumerate(self.tasks):
            task_label = Label(self.tasks_frame, text=task)
            task_label.bind('<Double-Button-1>', partial(self.replace_with_entry, i))
            task_label.grid(row=i, column=0)
        self.tasks_frame.pack()
    def replace_with_entry(self, i, event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.destroy()
        entry_widget = Entry(self.tasks_frame)
        entry_widget.grid(row=i, column=0)
root = Tk()
main_window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I also made another version that uses tkinter variables to include the text from the label in the entry. It could be modified to allow switching back to the label with the modified text.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.tasks = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
        self.list_tasks()
    def list_tasks(self):
        self.tasks_frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.task_widgets = []
        for i, task in enumerate(self.tasks):
            textvar = StringVar()
            textvar.set(task)
            task_label = Label(self.tasks_frame, textvariable=textvar)
            task_label.bind('<Double-Button-1>', partial(self.replace_with_entry, i))
            task_label.grid(row=i, column=0)
            task_entry = Entry(self.tasks_frame, textvariable=textvar)
            self.task_widgets.append((task_label, task_entry, textvar))
        self.tasks_frame.pack()
    def replace_with_entry(self, i, event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.grid_forget()
        self.task_widgets[i][1].grid(row=i, column=0)

root = Tk()
main_window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```